# Como acessar os valores de um objeto privado no PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
var_dump($bankAccount);
```

Que imprime:

> object(PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount)#35 (11) {
>   ["id":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   int(17929453)
>   ["bankCode":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(3) "104"
>   ["agencia":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(4) "0000"
>   ["agenciaDv":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   NULL   ["conta":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(5) "12345"
>   ["contaDv":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(1) "5"
>   ["documentNumber":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=> 
>   string(11) "04900000000"
>   ["documentType":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(3) "cpf"
>   ["legalName":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(12) "Maykel Esser"
>   ["dateCreated":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   object(DateTime)#37 (3) {
>       ["date"]=>
>       string(26) "2019-01-02 20:03:14.031000"
>       ["timezone_type"]=>
>       int(2)
>       ["timezone"]=>
>       string(1) "Z"   }   ["type":"PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount":private]=>
>   string(14) "conta_corrente" }

Ou seja, o retorno do var_dump de $bankAccount é um objeto.
Preciso do ID que está dentro deste objeto, e guardá-lo em uma variável para uso posterior.

Tentei puxar desta maneira:

```
$idBanco = $bankAccount->id;
```

Mas recebi o erro:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property PagarMe\Sdk\BankAccount\BankAccount::$id

Como proceder?

Comment: Se é privado, o acesso externo não é permitido. Leia a documentação da classe e veja se existe  método para tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a propriedade do objeto é privada, não é possível acessá-la diretamente, adicione uma método a classe que retorne esse id:

```
class Exemplo {
     // ...

     public function getId() {
          return $this->id;
     }
 }
```

Se não for possível, pode criar uma outra classe que estenderá a primeira e a use em no seu lugar

```
class MeuExemplo extends Exemplo {
     public function getId() {
          return $this->id;
      }
 }
```

Porém é necessário que a propriedade `id` seja do tipo `protected`

Comment: Se o campo é privado ele não será herdado nas classes filhas; apenas protected e public são herdados.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado pelo lembrete

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!